# Flutter Searching with voice

Tags: flutter, search, voice-recognition

I have made a search bar with TextField which is searching query if you type inside it by onChanged() property. Now i am using voice_recognition plugin. I am taking voice and assigning to the textController to show it inside the SearchBar. When i am assigning speech to the text controller it does not searching the query, just assigning and showing it inside TextField(SearchBar) unless I begin to type. How can i trigger my onChanged after user input voice inside TextField(SearchBar)
Here is my sample code:

// Here is Search Bar,  i am assigning voice transcription to the controller which assigns it to SearchBar. OnChanged property calls a function which is searching a query

```
  Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: TextField(
          onChanged: (text) {
            _con.refreshSearch(text);
          },
          onSubmitted: (text) {
            _con.saveSearch(text);
          },
          controller: _searchController,
          autofocus: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            hintText: S.of(context).search_for_product,
            hintStyle: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .caption
                .merge(TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
            prefixIcon:
                Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.1))),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.3))),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.1))),
            suffixIcon: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: scanBarcode,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/img/barcode.png",
                    height: 20,
                    color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                  ),
                ),
                _buildVoiceInput(
                  onPressed: _speechRecognitionAvailable && !_isListening
                      ? () => start()
                      : () => stop(),
                  label: _isListening ? S.of(context).listening : '',
                ),

              ],
            ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```